# Unable to use WHERE with Azure Mobile Offline Sync

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Services to store data on the device for Offline sync purposes, which works fine but I am having an issue with using `WHERE` when running the sync

```
var query = myTable.CreateQuery().Where(c => c.UserId == "123");
await myTable.PullAsync("testquery", query)
```

When I do this I get `BAD REQUEST` error but if I remove the `WHERE` clause from my query, it works fine but pulls the whole table to store it locally.

Anyone has any idea how to tackle this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok If anyone is wondering (this is a bit unusual) but the Table Entity Model in your Server backend should have column name starting with **Capital letter**.

> I was using `UserId` where on server backend it was `userId` so on
>   server backend I changed it to `UserId` and it works now.

This also considered a violation of naming convention in C# but sometimes I guess it's not easy to forget 'CamelCase' naming convention :)